# FB.Event.subscribe not working for method: 'send'

Tags: facebook

I'm using `FB.ui` to create a send dialog... I'm trying to get a callback after the user sent  the message, but it's not working for some reason.

I tried to use `FB.event.subscribe`

```
   FB.ui({                                                                                                                                                                   
     method: 'send',                                                                                                                                                         
     name: 'You\'re invited to join!',                                                                                                                          
     link: 'http://anexample.com',                                                                                                                                                              
   }); 

   FB.Event.subscribe('message.send',                                                                                                                                          
      function(response){                                                                                                                                                      
       alert('You sent a message from the URL ' + response);                                                                                                                                 
     }                                                                                                                                                                         
  );
```

Could anyone tell me what could be the problem with the subscribe ? The send works just fine.

Comment: You may leverage the `callback` argument to `FB.ui` as suggested in answer, but the fact that `message.send` event isn't fired looks like a bug, probably it's a good idea to [file a new bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create) and get it posted here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following callback:

```
FB.ui({ 
       method:'send',
       name: 'You\'re invited to join!',                                    
       link: 'http://anexample.com',
    },
    function(response) {
      //callback
    }
);
```

The callback you are using is for the [send](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) button.

Comment: Yeah noticed but couldn't answer my own question :) , cheers.

Comment: @Mr.Gando, you always can answer your own questions ;)

Comment: @JuicyScripter damn, thought I had to wait some time! , lost a free cookie I guess ?